# Signal R Connection terminated by Server in Production

Tags: angular, .net-core, signalr

I had add Signal R latest stable reales 1.1.0 in my .net core application and connect it with angular. my iis version is 10. i have 2 server one is local and other is production. 
in local server it's working fine but on production it's disconnected after 30 sec.
I got this message in console.

```
Information: (LongPolling transport) Poll terminated by server
Information: Connection disconnected.
```

I was wonder that it's working in local server perfectly fine but why not in production. i had check all configuration like CORS and iis app pool setting are same in both server.
any one have any other idea.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had fixed this. just update long polling transport to socket method and it's working fine.

thank you